# Is it possible to run Spark Cluster and a client as different users?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, whitelist

I am running Standalone Spark Cluster v 3.3 with one Master Node and 3 workers on a set of several VMs as "sparkcluster" user. I also have my Client application  on my local Windows box that connects to the Spark Cluster to load and persist the Data and eventually perform some data transformation. I can clearly see via Spark UI that my application connects to the Spark Cluster, however when I am trying to persist the data I am getting an exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/share/data/spark/load/TESTCACHE/f1ab4f4b-0b95-490b-b05c-5154cec2ae6b/fb51846b-c20d-42b3-bb3c-74abf71d10a2.part/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202211301636564407278350514085268_0003_m_000000_34 (exists=false, cwd=file:/app/spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/work/app-20221129201401-0055/0)
```

From what I found the reason for the exception is that I run Spark cluster as user A and my client application run as user B.

One possible solution is to deploy my application to the same location where I run Spark Cluster and run it as the same user, however it defeats the purpose of distributed system in my mind. Is there some sort of "white list" of users/IDs/clients I can define in Spark Cluster that will allow particular Client to perform all kind of operations on the Cluster?

complete Stacktrace :

```
17:33:21.372 [task-result-getter-2] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) (30.103.216.22 executor 0): java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/share/data/spark/tmp_load/b0ef0b46-da4c-474a-b381-72d79ba38161.part/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202211292233192374251041408678060_0002_m_000000_2 (exists=false, cwd=file:/app/spark/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3/work/app-20221129201401-0055/0)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$21(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Can you print out the full stack trace of your error? This gives more info as to what is going wrong. With the information you're giving, there are many possible causes. The following SO questions discuss a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814948/spark-csv-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-file